# Text changes height after adding unicode character

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I have HTML element with text content.
Font is set to sans-serif in CSS.
Text is updated via JavaScript.
Sometimes contains just ASCII characters but, sometimes, includes "➜" character. See following snippet:

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var chars = "A➜";
var i = 0;
function update() {
  i=1-i;
  text.innerText = "char: " + chars[i];
  setTimeout(update, 500);
}
update();
```

```css
div {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div id="text" />
```

This works fine in IE11 but in Chrome the element "wiggles":

[image: text element changing size]

It looks like this happens because different font is used to render "➜" character:

```
Arial—Local file(5 glyphs)
Segoe UI Symbol—Local file(1 glyph)
```

Is there a simple way to stabilize the height of whole element and position of static part of text?

One way seems to be using "Segoe UI Symbol" for whole element - but I prefer a different font for regular text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add a `line-height` style to your element:

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var chars = "A➜";
var i = 0;
function update() {
  i=1-i;
  text.innerText = "char: " + chars[i];
  setTimeout(update, 500);
}
update();
```

```css
div {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="text" />
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy fix would be to set the line-height in CSS

```js
var text = document.getElementById("x");
var chars = "A➜";
var i = 0;
function update() {
  i=1-i;
  text.innerText = chars[i];
  setTimeout(update, 500);
}
update();
```

```css
div {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  line-height: 1em;
}
#x {
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">char: <span id="x" /></div>
```