# Can specific text character change the line height?

Tags: html, css, overflow, font-size

I have this code:

```html
<p style="line-height: 1;overflow: hidden;">blah_blah</p>
<p>blah_blah</p>

<p style="line-height: 1;overflow: hidden;">qypj;,</p>
<p>qypj;,</p>
```

which results in (notice no underscore, and cut characters):

---

[image]

---

That is, it behaves that way in Firefox (66.0.3 on Windows 10). Other browsers seem to render the underscore. The above snippet runner also seems to work (even in Firefox), unless you run it in "Full page".

This Q is similar to [Text changes height after adding unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898803/text-changes-height-after-adding-unicode-character) except there are no tricks here. "_" is just a simple ASCII character.

My question is which behavior is the correct one.
Is specific character allowed to change line height (I thought it was only supposed to be font dependent)? Shouldn't `line-height: 1` imply it can fit exactly any text?

I suppose some characters are special, such as "p", "g", "j" (and possibly "_") that draw below its line. Still which behavior is the correct one. Is it considered overflow or not?

PS: Furthermore I find it funny **either** `overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: visible;` and `overflow-x: visible;overflow-y: hidden;` still causes this. Which seems more like an actual bug to me.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Replacing '_' with `&#x5f;` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My question is which behavior is the correct one.

All of them are correct because we don't have the same default font in all browsers and it's also different depending on the OS.

> Is specific character allowed to change line height (I thought it was only supposed to be font dependent)?

Character doesn't change `line-height`. To be more accurate, `line-height` is a property that can only be changed by setting `line-height` but you are probably confusing with the line box that is defined by the `line-height` and a character alone cannot change it.

> Shouldn't line-height: 1 imply it can fit exactly any text?

Not necessarely, `line-height:1` means that the line box will be equal to the `1xfont-size` <sup>1</sup> but is the font designed to include all the character inside this space? Probably most of them will do but we don't know.

---

Basically, you have two things to consider. The **content area** that is defined by the font properties and the **line box** that is defined by the line-height. We have no control over the first one and we can only control the second one.

Here is a basic example to illustrate:

```css
span {
 background:red;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family:monospace;
}

body {
 margin:10px 0;
 border-top:1px solid;
 border-bottom:1px solid;
 animation:change 2s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    line-height:0.2
  }
  
  to {
    line-height:2
  }
}
```

```html
<span >
blah_blah
</span>
```

The red is our content area and its height is defined by the font properties and if you inspect the element you will see it has a height equal to `23px` (not `20px` like the `font-size`) and the borders define our line box that we control using the line-height.

So if the `line-height` is equal to 1 we will have a line box equal to `20px` which is not enough to contain the `23px` of the content area thus it will get truncated and we may probably hide some characters (or a part of them) which is logical:

```css
span {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

body {
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 1;
  overflow:hidden;
}

html {
 overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<span>
blah_blah ÂÄ j p
</span>
```

a different `font-size` will remove the underscore in Firefox:

```css
span {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

body {
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 1;
  overflow:hidden;
}

html {
 overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<span>
blah_blah ÂÄ j p
</span>
```

[image]

Another example with a Google Font where the result should be the same cross browser. The underscore is visible but not the `^`/`¨`

```css
span {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: 'Gugi', cursive;

}

body {
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 1;
  overflow:hidden;
}

html {
 overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gugi" rel="stylesheet">
<span>
blah_blah ÂÄ j p
</span>
```

[image]

Another example where the underscore is not visible:

```css
span {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;

}

body {
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 1;
  overflow:hidden;
}

html {
 overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<span>
blah_blah ÂÄ j p
</span>
```

[image]

You can clearly see that we have a different overflow everytime we use a different font which confirms that this is font related. We have no control over it unless we know how the font is designed.

---

Related questions:

[Understanding CSS2.1 specification regarding height on inline-level boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52282391/8620333)

[Why is there space between line boxes, not due to half leading?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52280267/8620333)

[Line height issue with inline-block elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54341767/8620333)

---

Here is a good article to get more accurate details and calculation: https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align

A quote from this article:

> It becomes obvious that setting `line-height: 1` is a **bad practice**. I remind you that unitless values **are font-size relative, not content-area relative**, and dealing with a virtual-area smaller than the content-area is the origin of many of our problems.

[image]

<sup>1 : I considered a simplified explanation but in reality the calculation of the line box is not only relate to the line-height property.</sup>

Comment: I mean, if I understand it correctly, Firefox considers the space of `line-box - line-height` an overflow. Meanwhile other browsers consider it not an overflow. So which is the correct behavior? Can't be both, (at least in ideal world). Not sure how default font matters here (which you open your answer with). Unless it is some kind of bitmap monospace font, then all fonts draw below the text line for esthetic reasons on some characters...

Comment: @krOoze what you mean by *the space of line-box - line-height*? .. the line-height is defining the line box. And yes the font matters because not all of them have the same properties and not all of them are drawn the same way (the screenshot I added show a different behavior between Chrome and Firefox because the monospace font is not the same)

Comment: @krOoze and if you run the snippet where I added the animation you will notice an overflow on the top and the bottom which is not necessarely equal and will not be the same for all the fonts too

Comment: @krOoze added more details and examples, hope it more clear

Comment: Took me some time to grok this. I think this is as close to answer as it gets. This example: https://jsfiddle.net/2qawxm50/ seems particularly illustrative to me if you wish to add it.

Answer (score 2):

If I use the browser tools in Firefox to inspect my snippet below, there is no height difference between the lines with and without underscore. The only difference is caused by the `line-height` setting: 16px with `line-height: 1`, 19.2 px with the browser's default line-height. So the underscore doesn't make a difference here (Firefox 66.0.3 on Mac), and it is visible in both cases.

Note that I set margins to 0 to see the "pure" line-height without distances *between*  the lines. Also, I didn't specify a font-familiy setting, so the default font of the browser for `p` tags is used.

The only reason for what you describe which I can think of is a font with very particular dimensions/settings, where the descenders (i.e. the parts of letters like p q j which extend below the baseline) are *not* inside the line-height as defined by the font.

After a bunch of comments back and forth: I suppose it could be caused by the different default (system) fonts on Windows and Mac. Still a bug, I would say (*if*  you are using the default font).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  background: #fb6;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p style="line-height: 1;overflow: hidden;">blah_plah</p>
<p style="line-height: 1;overflow: hidden;">blah plah</p>
<p>blah_plah</p>
<p>blah plah</p>
```

Comment: OK, I may have been inconsistent in the Q with "line height" vs "line-height". Although this is interesting. Considering the "container" of all the cases is the same I don't see a good reason why `overflow` should apply to some subpart of it. I guess it is up to what the specs say... (and whether or not should I report it to Mozzilla)

Comment: Apparently the difference is between Windows and Mac: We both use FF 66.0.3, but I am on a Mac

Comment: No, my observation matches yours. The `height` is the same. Only `line-height` differs.

Comment: Actually I suppose it could be caused by the different default (*system*) fonts...

Comment: Definitely. I should add the "p" etc to the snippet. Those are guaranteed to write below text line. Underscore could be aligned with text in some fonts...

Comment: I just replaced some "b"s with "p"s. I still see everything, i.e. the full descender of the "p". What does it look like on Windows?

Comment: Do you run it in online snippet editor, or do you save it to `htm` and open that file?

Comment: Until now only in the snippet here. But same behaviour in Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XwrVwm

Comment: FWIW, I just tried it in a "real website": `line-height: 1`, `overflow: hidden;`, both with the webfont I had set and then also with the default font, in Firefox 66.0.3 on Mac: The underscore always remains visible...

Answer (score 2):

The [default line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) (depending on the font-family) when not otherwise specified is about 1.2 in most browsers. This includes Firefox.

This would explain why the underscore did not show in FireFox when the line-height was set to 1 - the bottom was of the line was cut off. So I don't think it's entirely to do with the font (although this does contribute), but also browser defaults.

Some font-sizes are bigger than other even at seemingly the "same" font size (as I'm sure you've seen when typing documents in e.g. Georgia vs Times new Roman/Baskerville ; so you wouldn't be guaranteed that text would always show on a specified line height of 1 (or 1.2). There are ways of measuring a font in pixels however

Hope this helps

Comment: In the snippet in my answer the underscore is visible regardless of the line-height (also in Firefox), so the underscore is definitely *not*  "cut off" by `line-height: 1`.

Comment: I couldn't see in Firefox until I set line height to 1.1

Comment: Hm - must be a different Firefox version then, reacting differently. I am on a Mac and FF 66.0.3

Comment: @Johannes also, only the 3rd out of the 4th 'blah blah' shows with an underline in FF on windows (latest version) - so yours is not a universal answer

Comment: Note my other comment - seems to be a difference between FF Windows and Mac.

Comment: @Johannes did you try to view the problem @ line-height of 1.1 on your Mac?

Comment: Yes: still visible (which is logical, since it's even visible with `line-height: 1`)

Comment: @RachelGallen I mean it makes sense it is `1.2`. Nobody wants to read crammed text (i.e. it is used as line distance). But definition of `1.0` is that it should match the text of a given font, no?

Comment: @krOoze no. Font sizes differ. Have you scrolled through the fonts in Adobe or Word recently? They are not all the same at 10pt or 12pt.. why should they all fit in 1em?

Comment: @RachelGallen Regardles whether they are 10pt or 12pt, they are 100 % of their own size. Not `1em`, `1` (unitless).

Comment: @krOoze read this [article](http://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align)