# Using Google Fonts, text does not vertically align within the line height

Tags: css, text, fonts, vertical-alignment

I want the buttons to include text, I am able to format everything correctly, but when switching to Google Fonts, the font style itself seems to have some sort of bottom padding and I am not sure how to get rid of this. (See the image below) I want the text to be vertically aligned within the button.

[image: TEST Button Example Images]

The below image simply does not include my line-height styling, notice that there is still a noticeable area below the font that will not go away.

[image]

Comment: Please share your code on here (and on https://codepen.io/pen/) to check your problem

Comment: *the font style itself seems to have some sort of bottom padding* --> you answered your self, the font may include some spacing that you cannot control and this is a part of the font properties. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55978512/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for linking that related question. That helped a lot. I'll consider this answered since the answers there cover this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am considering this question answered by the helpful answers and resources from the [linked issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978130/can-specific-text-character-change-the-line-height) provided by [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).