# How to get rid of unwanted padding on top and bottom of any html tag (div, p, span) when writing text inside

Tags: html, css

I want to create a div, p or span that contains some text with a colored background and I wanted to make the div, p or span fits exactly the words inside of it.
here's what I tried doing:

```css
.bigHeader {
  font-size: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: #FA7268;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p class='bigHeader'>Text</p>
```

padding right and left are exactly as I want, but padding top and right aren't exactly as I excpected.

**here's what I got:**

[image]

**and here's what I want:**

[image]

regardless of the different sizes, shortly I want the padding top and bottom to disapear.

Comment: `<p className='bigHeader'>` should probably be `<p class='bigHeader'>`

Comment: it's just cause I'm using react, it has nothing to do with that, thank you mate.

Comment: Try to use this text and you will want to keep that space: `ÂÊrjkp`

Comment: I'm obliged to have it that way brother

Comment: check this to understand what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/g7xfr2za/2/

Comment: Yes I know but I don't have any accents on my text and I really need it that way, thank you mate

Comment: and to understand what is happening and probably fix this, you can read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55978512/8620333

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `line-height`:

```css
.bigHeader {
  font-size: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: #FA7268;
  color: white;
  line-height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<p class='bigHeader'>Text</p>
```

It may be useful to set a percentage font size on `html` and `body` (we use 62.5% where I work) and then use REM units for font-size and line-height. This ensures your sizing stays constant.