# Why does the ▴ utf8 charcter change the line height of my th?

Tags: html, css, utf-8

I am developing a website with a sortable table on it. The table-header is shown here:

[image: th without arrow]

As soon as I insert the sort-direction character (arrow up or down) into the span.sortdirchar, the height of the `<th>` element changes from 20 to 22. The problem is that the character is hight than the line height for some reason:

[image: th with arrow]

So the `th` wraps around the characters height (more than 16px), although the inspect-tool tells me that my span is only 16px tall.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55978512/8620333

Comment: The simple answer you probably don't want to hear is: those are two different fonts. Just read the linked answer.

Comment: Yeah - i'd make the line height of the text match the height of the arrow indicator, then you won't get the jiggle