# CSS background: Letters like g,p outside background box

Tags: css, fonts, background, background-color

I have the following scenario: I want a background with no padding behind a heading but certain letters - as g,p -  are outside the box.

Seems pretty simple but can't find a way to include all letters seamlessly:

- No letter portion outside background box
- No extra space/color on top of l's or capitals for example.

Can you please help?

```css
h2{
  background:#b2bec3;
  color:#444;
  display:block;
  font-family:'Roboto';
  font-weight:700;
  line-height:1;
  font-size:35px;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<h2>This is a heading or a paragraph text</h2>
```

Comment: This really isn't too practical but changing the lineheight to 1.4 would get you part of the way. Text is **supposed** to have space above and below to separate it from other text lines.

Comment: this is simply impossible without JS (at least in a generic way), read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55978512/8620333

Comment: ^ don't forget that you have letters like `ÂÊ` and `_`

Answer (score 1):

Like @Temani Afif said in the comment below your post, you'll have to delve into JS.
Best option is to bump up your line height slightly

```
    line-height: 1.2;
```