# Filter effect is spilling out

Tags: css, svg, text, svg-filters

Consider a `div` with some bumped up text and a `filter`. The `filter` is restricted to `100%×100%` of the `objectBoundingBox`.

However, when we apply a `feFlood`, we can see how this spills outside the element's `padding-box` (identical to the `border-box`) here. Why?

(the `box-shadow` highlights the boundary here)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&display=swap');

body {
    font: 900 8em/ 1 fjalla one, 
        sans-serif;
}

svg { position: fixed }

div {
    margin: .375em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #00f; /* padding-box boundary highlight */
    background: #00f7 content-box;
    filter: url(#f)
}

div:nth-of-type(2n) { padding-bottom: 1lh }
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <filter id="f" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" 
          x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
    <feFlood flood-color="#f00"/>
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </filter>
</svg>
<div>HELLO</div>
<div>HELLO</div>
```

This seems to depend on the `line-height` and on the particular `font-family` chosen (why?), but changing those is **not** a solution.

How do I fix this? It's particularly problematic when I want to apply a filter effect on half the height because this height is miscomputed, which triggers an avalanche of subsequent miscomputed filter effects.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&display=swap');

body {
    font: 900 8em/ 1 fjalla one, 
        sans-serif;
}

svg { position: fixed }

div {
    margin: .375em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #00f; /* padding-box boundary highlight */
    background: #00f7 content-box;
    filter: url(#f)
}

div:nth-of-type(2n) { padding-bottom: 1lh }
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <filter id="f" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" 
          x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
    <feFlood flood-color="#f00" height=".5"/>
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </filter>
</svg>
<div>HELLO</div>
<div>HELLO</div>
```

Comment: by the way, using overflow: hidden on the second example give a good result but I suppose you don't want to hide any overflow

Comment: What was the desired result?

Comment: @Kosh not having the red (from `feFlood`) spill outside the boundary of the `border-box` (the blue outline).

Comment: It might be worth considering doing your text with SVG text rather than HTML text - if that's an option.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is related to the SVG. The SVG filter apply to the **content area**. It's the area that depends on the font properties and you cannot control it by changing the `line-height` ([Can specific text character change the line height?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55978130/8620333))

The content area is that area you see when you select your text:

[image]

Or when you apply a background to an inline element:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&display=swap');

body {
    font: 900 8em/ 1 fjalla one, 
        sans-serif;
}

svg { position: fixed }

div {
    margin: .375em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #00f; /* padding-box boundary highlight */
    background: #00f7 content-box;
    filter: url(#f)
}

div + div {filter:none}

div + div span {background :red}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <filter id="f" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" 
          x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
    <feFlood flood-color="#f00"/>
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </filter>
</svg>
<div>HELLO</div>
<div><span>HELLO</span></div>
```

As you can see, in all the cases the content area is overflowing the div because your `line-height` is defining the height of the **line box** to be smaller than the **content area**.

Not sure if you can change the behavior of the SVG filter but I am sure that you cannot control that content area.

Comment: So the **content area** is different from the `content-box`? Because the text fits inside the `content-box`. And `line-height: 1` plus the font were carefully chosen so that the text fits inside the `content-box`, but with not much room up and down. Precisely because having more space above and below the text would ruin the SVG filter effect I want.

Comment: @Ana yes they are different. the content area is defined within the font properties and even if you think the text fits inside that space in reality it doesn't because the font designer added space above and below the letters that are part of the letter (and don't forget that we can have `ÂÄÊ`). I am afraid it will be difficult to find a font like you want unless you edit it yourself.

Comment: @Ana content area and content-box will be the same when you consider an inline element. you cannot change the height of an inline element because that height is font related. You can only control the line-height that will define the height of the generated box for that inline element (when placed inside a line box) but it will never affect the content area. Even if you set line-height:0 you can see that area: https://jsfiddle.net/ak6x4hqo/).