Correct font baseline with CSS
I have a font (specifically Caslon) that's not vertically centered in its bounding box.
How can I use CSS to adjust the vertical alignment to better match its bounding box?
For example, here's a screenshot of Caslon compared with Inter.

A few differences:

Inter's baseline is closer to it's bounding box.
Inter's descenders touch (actually slightly dip below) the bottom of the bounding box.
Inter's overall visual line height much more closely matches the CSS-computed line height.

Due to these differences I'm having a hard time creating a visually balanced page.
For reference, to generate the screenshot I used CSS very similar to the following:
.text {
    font-size: 3.75rem;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

Note: I'm not including a full replication because Caslon's not a free font.

Your website users don’t see the bounding boxes. So please edit your post to articulate and/or illustrate the actual visual balancing problem you’re having, and include what you’ve tried so far to solve it.

@BrettDonald Add some padding, now you definitely notice and have to correct for this baseline.

... and surely asymmetric padding or relative positioning would be the way to correct for it?

you cannot do this, it's a font-related thing: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55978130/8620333
