How to center font vertically in it's line-height
Im trying to implement a special font called 'Hagrid' which was bought by the client here: https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/zetafonts/hagrid
Demo-page: https://fonttest.web-fuchs.net/
When using the font on the website it is not vertically aligned to the line. On the site: fonttest.web-fuchs.net you can see the first H1 is in Hagrid font. There you can see that the Text is not centered to its own line-height. At the 'sans H1' for example, you can see what I would expected normally of a font: that it's letters are centered to its own line-height. The italic version however seems to work better, but maybe a bit too low.
The negative effect is when using the font, e.g. in a button where a top and bottom border is set. This makes the font appear not centered inside the button.
Is the problem the font itself or is it possible to fix that somehow with css?
Update: I just figured out, that the font works fine on Mac, but not on Windows.
line-height is set to 1


Do you mean vertically?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/55978130/2518285

The font designer sets the metrics. If it causes problems with your layout try some asymmetric padding, or adjusting the line-height.

@David The Text 'Hagrid H1 AaBbGg' should be in the horizontal center of the line.

@BrettDonald Adjusting the line-height is not making things better, unfortunately. Asymmetric padding would only work on a one-line text. So Maybe the font is just 'messed up' ?

@Stefan you mean vertical. You are saying the characters are too high and should be lower ... that’s a difference in their vertical position, not their horizontal position. Please edit your post to clarify.

What is the actual problem that this is causing in your layout? Can you show us?

@BrettDonald i changed the title to vertical. On the site: https://fonttest.web-fuchs.net/ you can see the first H1 is in Hagrid font. There you can see that the Text is not centered to its own line-height. At the 'sans H1' for example you can see what is expected normally of a font: that its centered to its own line-height.

Line-height is usually set to something higher than 1, I believe the usual value is 1.2 or higher.

As stated previously, this is something the font designer has put in place and CSS can't really resolve it. You could fake something with a proper line-height and padding-top but it's going to be highly font/size/weight/style specific...etc.

@Stefan so we have established that the font is not vertically centered in its line box. There's nothing you can do about that. But users don't see the line boxes, so the simple fact that it's not centered is not relevant to a user. Is the font positioning negatively affecting your layout in a way that a user can see? If so, please illustrate (by editing your post) how this issue is negatively affecting your layout.

@BrettDonald I adjusted the post. The negative effect is when using the font, e.g. in a button where a top and bottom border is set. This makes the font appear not centered inside the button.

@Stefan but you can easily compensate with asymmetric padding.

@BrettDonald With padding I would need to apply a padding to every text on the page and always adjust the padding to the font-size. I just figured out, that the font works fine on Macs but not on Windows.

Add text-align: center; CSS property on the tag.
As I saw your webpage has only <h1> and <p> tags.
So you can add new style like this
h1, p {
    text-align: center;
}


The question says horizontal, but really means vertical.

The question has been edited.
Previously it was written how to center horizontally.

If you want to center 'h1' and 'p' elements horizontally, you need to assign 'text-align: center' to the parent div in CSS.

The question says horizontal, but really means vertical.
